# Unable to concatenate html

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

“I’m trying to make an `Ajax call`, which is successful. But when I try to print the response it does not concatenate the "success" or "failure: string with "initial value"

it prints the middle vale and Also, if i put `console.log` inside success or failure it prints the value. It does not work outside the Ajax call

```
loadData : function(groupRID, serviceName) {
    var html = 'initial value';
    var params = {
        codeGroupRid : groupRID,
        outputFormat : 'json'
    };
    html +=' middle'
    Util.Functions.eAjax(serviceName, params, {
        success : function(response) {
            html += ' Success';
            return html;
        },
        failure : function(errMsg) {
            html += ' Failure';
            return html;
        }
    });      
},
```

Expected is - `initial value middle Success`

Actual is - `initial value middle`

Comment: `ajax` (Asynchronous Javascript and Xml) is... **asynchronous**. It means it returns immediately, before the response is obtained. And `callback` parts (*success`, `failure`) never `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return html;` part from success and failure callbacks cause ajax is asynchronous. If you use return inside the callback it return before response is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gokul Raj K.N. said - Ajax is asynchronous method by default. So:

**Recommended solution:**

You should add `function` parameter to `loadData` method which can be done like:

```
loadData(groupRID, serviceName, function (result) {
    let loaded_data = result;
    // do something with loaded data
});
```

And `loadData` method with `callback`:

```
loadData : function(groupRID, serviceName, callback) {
    var html = 'initial value';
    var params = {
        codeGroupRid : groupRID,
        outputFormat : 'json'
    };
    html +=' middle'
    Util.Functions.eAjax(serviceName, params, {
        async: false,
        success : function(response) {
            html += ' Success';
            callback(html);
        },
        failure : function(errMsg) {
            html += ' Failure';
            callback(html);
        }
    });      
},
```

**Not recommended solution:**

You can easy change `async` parameter to make it synchronous.

> **true** if this request should run asynchronously. Setting this to **false** should generally be avoided, since it will cause the UI to be blocked, the user won't be able to interact with the browser until the request completes.
>   Defaults to: **true**

```
loadData : function(groupRID, serviceName) {
    var html = 'initial value';
    var params = {
        codeGroupRid : groupRID,
        outputFormat : 'json'
    };
    html +=' middle'
    Util.Functions.eAjax(serviceName, params, {
        async: false,
        success : function(response) {
            html += ' Success';
            return html;
        },
        failure : function(errMsg) {
            html += ' Failure';
            return html;
        }
    });      
},
```

Comment: Sending the request as synchronous is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: We aren't talking about bad ideas, but about the possibility of implementing a solution. Look my quoted comment - `Setting this to false should generally be avoided, since it will cause the UI to be blocked`

Comment: OP is asking how to solve the issue. Using a synchronous request is exceedingly rare because of the issues it causes. I would argue that your suggestion doesn't really help solve the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer, add `recommended` solution by @EvanTrimboli remark.